# Saving scraped data with the correct encoding

Tags: python, csv, unicode, export-to-csv

I am scraping **product description** information from [Books to Scrape](https://books.toscrape.com/), and saving the data to a csv file. Here is the code to initialize the `DictWriter`:

```py
with open('book_data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as file:
    dictWriter = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=['Title', 'Price', 'Rating', 'Description', 'UPC'])
    dictWriter.writeheader()`
```

The program parses the HTML of each page, and saves it to a `dict`:

```py
dictWriter.writerow(
    {'Title': title, 'Price': price, 'Rating': rating, 'Description': description, 'UPC': upc})
```

The program works fine, however, characters with accents, such as (`à` `ê` `î` `ô` `ú`), are unrecognizable in the csv file. I outlined a few examples in red in the screenshot below:

[image]

I suspect this is an encoding issue. I thought using `encoding='utf8'` with the `DictWriter` would resolve this; however, it did not.

### Questions:

1. What's going on here, why is this happening?
2. How can I correct this, and save the data in a readable format.

Comment: Are you sure you’ve opened the CSV file using the correct encoding? Are you sure you’ve scraped the data correctly to begin with?

Comment: When I opened the `csv` file I used `utf-8` encoding; what this the correct encoding?

Answer (score 2):

The following demo shows a way to get (most of) the details. The output CSV file is correctly written in utf-8 format.

`req.content` is used to pass the returned bytes to BeautifulSoup to allow it to parse the HTML and apply the correct encoding. requests also attempts to determine the encoding based on the returned headers (used with `req.text`) but as BeautifulSoup is parsing the HTML it can usually make a better choice.

`req.encoding` could be used to display encoding for `req.text`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://books.toscrape.com/"
req_main = requests.get(url)
soup_main = BeautifulSoup(req_main.content, "html.parser")

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=["Title", "Price", "Description"])
    csv_output.writeheader()
    
    for article in soup_main.find_all("article", class_="product_pod"):
        req_book = requests.get(url + article.a['href'])
        soup_book = BeautifulSoup(req_book.content, "html.parser")
        
        row = {
            "Title" : soup_book.h1.text,
            "Price" : soup_book.find("p", class_="price_color").text,
            "Description" : soup_book.find("div", id="product_description").find_next("p").text,
        }
        
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

The output as shown in `Notepad++` with `utf-8` encoding:

[image: utf-8 screenshot]

Notepad++ is able to correctly display the `utf-8` encoded characters. If the displayed encoding is changed to display ANSI encoding you get:

[image: ansi screenshot]

You need to ensure your editor can correctly display utf-8 encoding text.

Comment: Thank you, problem resolved! I was using `requests.text`, and not `requests.content` to build the `soup` object.  **Question**: I thought `r.content` was used to return the response in `bytes`, So why did `r.text` not work in this scenario?

Comment: It allows BeautifulSoup to parse the raw HTML and apply the correct encoding